# Where is Sapling Tree in 2.79?

Tags: sapling-addon

I work on 2.79 full release version. I have the sapling tree add-on activated.
All tutorials i can find show the addon under Add>Curve>add tree.
Its not there :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. If I enable the addon. Then Sapling Tree Gen appears on the Add>Curve menu. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNeay.png

Comment: You trying to find it within the shift+A menu in object mode? Or do you search for it in the create panel in the tool shelf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is under *Sapling Tree Gen* now

[image]

Comment: im just blind apparently. thats all